# What is the workflow to sculpt construction lines using the Curve Stroke Method?

Tags: sculpting

I was watching [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M607N7PV6Nc) and around the 5:50 mark he starts cutting (sculpting) construction lines using the Curve Stroke Method. The problem is that I can't reproduce the effect and the Blender manual seems to leave out the Curve Stroke Method. Can someone shed some light on how to use this technique?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think I figured it out,

after you choose your brush type(scrape maybe)

and choose your stroke type to curve, make the curve by <kbd>Ctrl LMB</kbd>  all over the place

then try pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> a couple of times, or just keep holding it down, or increase the strength of the brush.

I didnt know this was possible, nice

[image]

Comment: Added in 2.72 - see almost at the [end of the release notes](https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:Ref/Release_Notes/2.72/Painting) for some keys to use, and it is also available in texture painting. This appears to be a feature that hasn't been added to the manual.